# Phone app of ICS doesnot have CATEGORY.LAUNCHER

Tags: android, launcher

I was checking android Phone app code . What I noticed was manifest file does not have CATEGORY.LAUNCHER . Without it how is it appearing on launcher ?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the answer as well. Both implementation details and philosophy behind this implementation are interesting for me, as it really looks inconsistent and doesn't match official documentation.

Comment: I still dont know how that works.